# How to create and use editor template in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

I am new to MVC; I would like to create two editor templates one for readonly textbox and another for editable textbox.

Editable textbox code:

```
@model string
@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m,new {size = 35})
```

Readonly textbox:

```
@model string
@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m,new {@readonly = "readonly",size = 35})
```

But I am not sure how to use them in views, can i give editor template name in views?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't actually call these within the View.  You would use Html.Editor or Html.EditorFor of course, however, to associate with these, you need to do so within your model.

Model

```
[UIHint("NameOfYourEditorTemplate")]
public string EditableText { get; set; }

[UIHint("NameOfYourEditorTemplate")]
public string ReadonlyText { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cant I do some thing like:<div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, "EditableTextbox")</div>

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't work that way.  Every example and time I've used EditorTemplates, I've always used them the way I mentioned.